# python - How to change popup color in kivy

Tags: python, python-2.7, kivy

I am using `python-2.7` and `kivy`.I am using `Popup` widget. By default Popup appears in grey color.
After i add `self.background = " "` then popup color changed into white color But how to change into another color Apart from white.

## test.py

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.uix.popup import Popup

class Pop(Popup):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Pop, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.background = ""
        self.open()


class TestApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Pop()


TestApp().run()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set `background:` to picture file (*jpeg, jpg, gif, png*). In the example, we are using *yellow.png* file.

## Example

### main.py

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.popup import Popup
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.lang import Builder


Builder.load_string('''
#:kivy 1.11.0

<abc>:
    title : "change title color"
    title_color: 1, 0, 0, 1    # red title

    background: 'yellow.png'

    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "vertical"

        GridLayout:
            cols: 1
            Label:
                bold: True
                text: "make label bold"
                color: 1, 0, 0, 1    # red color text

            Label:
                markup: True
                text: "[b][color=008000]make[/color] label [color=3333ff]bold[/color][/b]"

''')


class abc(Popup):
    pass


class PopupApp(App):
    title = 'Popup Demo'

    def build(self):
        self._popup = abc()
        return Button(text="press me", on_press=self._popup.open)


PopupApp().run()
```

## Output

[image: Img01]

Answer (score 0):

change the "background" property to: background: ''
and pick the color you want to change your background to and it will work.

Example:

```
<MyPopup@Popup>:
    title: "White bg Popup"
    background: ''
    background_color: (1, 1, 1, 1)
```